# C++ Exception constructor error because of returned string

Tags: c++, throw

I have some problem with a returned string: I have a function that returns a string:

```
std::string foo(const std::string& paramIn)
{
  return ("My message" + paramIn);
}
```

and I have an exception class:

```
class MyException : public std::exception
{
private:
  std::string m_msg;

public:
  MyException(std::string& msg) : m_msg(msg) {}
  virtual ~MyException() throw() {}

  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return m_msg.c_str();
  }
};
```

The problem appears when I throw an `MyException` that takes as argument the `foo` function's return:

```
throw MyException(foo("blabla"));
```

It says:

```
/home/me/my_proj/main.cpp: In member function ‘std::string ConfigFile::getClassifierExtractorType()’:
/home/me/my_proj/main.cpp:79:96: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyException::MyException(std::string)’
     throw MyException(foo("blabla"));
                                    ^
/home/me/my_proj/main.cpp:79:96: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/me/my_proj/main.hpp:5:0,
                 from /home/me/my_proj/main.cpp:1:
/home/me/my_proj/CMyExceptions.hpp:38:3: note: MyException::MyException(std::string&)
   MyException(std::string& msg) : m_msg(msg) {}
   ^
/home/me/my_proj/CMyExceptions.hpp:38:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’
/home/me/my_proj/CMyExceptions.hpp:32:7: note: MyException::MyException(const MyException&)
 class MyException : public MyIOException
       ^
```

If I just put the returned string in a variable:

```
std::string msg = foo("blabla");
throw MyException(msg);
```

It works fine (no errors), why? How to fix this?

Comment: constructor parameter should be `const string&`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rvalues do not bind to non-const lvalue references. Change your constructor:

```
MyException(std::string const & msg)
//                      ^^^^^
```

In modern C++, you could even take the string by value:

```
MyException(std::string msg) noexcept : m_msg(std::move(msg)) { }
```

This has the added advantage that your exception class can be constructed without itself throwing exceptions, unlike your original code.

Comment: I have also tried to change `const std::string foo(const std::string& paramIn)`, but it did not worked

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon: const rvalues also don't bind to non-const lvalue references.

Comment: What other changes will fix it (without `noexcept`)?

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon: Do exactly what I say in the first code snippet.

Comment: Using a value in the ctor was always possible, wasn't it? Only less efficient (no move, no rvalue refs).

Comment: It works if I add `MyException(**const** std::string msg)`. Can you add more possibilities, as without `noexcept`?

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon: Do *exactly* as I say. Attention to little details like `&`, but easiest to just copy-paste.

Comment: I have post the `&`, but not in the comment. It works